# What tokens are endless despite having a limited supply?

Tags: eldritch-horror

What tokens should be treated as unlimited in supply despite having a limited number in the game box, i.e. focus tokens, travel tickets, and the like? Naturally it makes the game 'harder' for the investigators should these run out, so I was curious what items have been confirmed to be allowed to have replacements simply because the game did not come with enough tokens for these edge case game sessions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any token, other than Clues, Gates, and Monsters, is always available.
>   If there are no remaining tokens of the specified type, track those
>   tokens on paper or with a small object such as a coin.

Source: [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), "Component Limitations" (page 3)